# Showing Convergence in Distribution of a sequence of random variables taking values in the set of integers

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X_n$ and $X$ be random variables taking values in $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $\text{lim inf}_{n→∞} P(X_n = k) \geq P(X = k)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show that $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$.

$$$$My attempt to the solution is as follows : As $X_n$ and $X$ both take values in $\mathbb{Z}$ so proving $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ is equivalent to proving that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n=k)=P(X=k)$$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that there exists a $k_0$ such that the above does not hold. Then there exits an $\epsilon_0$ such that there exists a sub sequence $X_{n_r}$ such that $$|P(X_{n_r}=k_0)-P(X=k_0)|>\epsilon_0$$ for all $r \geq 1$. Now as $\mathbb{Z}$ is countable so we can write $\mathbb{Z}=\{k_0, k_1, k_2,...... \}$. Now as the sequence $P(X_{n_r}=k_0)$ is bounded so there exists a sub sequence $X_{n_{r_s}}$ such that $P(X_{n_{r_s}}=k_0)$ converges. Again as the sequence $P(X_{n_{r_s}}=k_1)$ is bounded we can again find a sub sequence which converges. And continuing this argument we can find a sub sequence say $X_{n_{r_t}}$ such that $P(X_{n_{r_t}}=k)$ converges for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and so we can write $$\lim_{t \to \infty}P(X_{n_{r_t}}=k)=a_k$$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and for some sequence $a_k$. Now we know that for a double sequence $f(m, n)$ such that $f(m, n) \geq 0$ for every $m, n$, we have $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \text{lim inf}_{n→∞} f(m, n) \leq \text{lim inf}_{n→∞} \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} f(m, n)$$. So now we have for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $$a_k=\text{lim inf}_{t \to \infty}P(X_{n_{r_t}}=k) \geq \text{lim inf}_{n \to \infty}P(X_n=k) \geq P(X=k) \\ \implies 1=\text{lim inf}_{t \to \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X_{n_{r_t}}=k_i) \geq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\text{lim inf}_{t \to \infty}P(X_{n_{r_t}}=k_i) \\ \geq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\text{lim inf}_{n \to \infty}P(X_n=k_i) \geq \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=k_i)=1$$ and hence equality must hold everywhere and so we get $$\lim_{t \to \infty}P(X_{n_{r_t}}=k)=P(X=k)$$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. But earlier we assumed that $$|P(X_{n_r}=k_0)-P(X=k_0)|>\epsilon_0$$ for every $r \geq 1$ which is a contradiction and so we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}P(X_n=k)=P(X=k)$$ for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and hence $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$.

$$$$Is My Solution Correct?

Comment: Hint: I think you might be supposed to use a version of the portmanteau lemma

Comment: Is My Solution correct?